# std::function vs function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, std-function

- Is there any differences?
- Which is the best way to "save/transfer" function?

  ```
  function<void(int)> fcn = 
                      [](int par) {std::cout<<"fcn: "<<par<<std::endl; };
  void(*fcn_a)(int) = 
                      [](int par) {std::cout<<"fcn_a: "<<par<<std::endl; };


  fcn(12);
  fcn_a(12);
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::function` is more generic - you can store in it any callable object with correct signature (function pointer, method pointer, object with `operator()`) and you can construct `std::function` using [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Function pointer can only accept functions with correct signature but might be slightly faster and might generate slightly smaller code.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of a non-capturing lambda, using a function pointer would be faster than using `std::function`. This is because `std::function` is a far more general beast and uses type-erasure to store the function object passed to it. It achieves this through type-erasure, implying that you end up with a call to `operator()` being virtual.

OTOH, non-capturing lambdas are implicitly convertible to the corresponding function pointer. If you need a full-fledged closure however, you will have to assign the lambda to `std::function`, or rely on type deduction through templates, whenever possible.